# .NET 6 Docker: Why I can't see env variable in Docker container?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, environment-variables

There is the next section in `launchsettings.json` of the ASP.NET Core Web API project:

```json
"Docker": {
  "commandName": "Docker",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:443;http://+:80",
    "MYSECRETS__MYDBPASSWORD": "MyPassValue"
  },
  "publishAllPorts": true,
  "useSSL": true
}
```

I run the app in a docker container and my application works fine taking a password from `MYSECRETS__MYDBPASSWORD` env variable. But when I try to `printenv` (as root user) inside the container, I can't see my env var. I also tried to find it in `Docker Desktop -> Inspect` but without success.

In Visual Studio 2022 -> Output -> Container Tools I also can't see that the variable is passed to the container with `-e` argument.

If I change the password to something wrong in `launchsettings.json` and re-run the container, application fails because of the wrong authentication. So, the env variable is definitely inside the container but I can't see it.

Why I can't see it and how it's passed inside the container?

Comment: environment variables are passed to docker container with the "docker run" command. This [link](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-https-aspnet-core/#environment) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Could you kindly the solution below, if you need further help,please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that Visual Studio sets environment variables **per process** when run Web API project in Docker. Env vars can be seen the next way:

```bash
# Find your dotnet process ID
ps faux
# Show env vars for your process ID (PID)
cat /proc/[PID]/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
```

But when I run the application via `docker-compose` project with setting env vars in `docker-compose.override.yml` file, they can be seen with simple `printenv` command.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you are using Visual Studio, so [you can use `docker-compose.override.yml` to Override Visual Studio's Docker Compose configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/docker-compose-properties?view=vs-2022#overriding-visual-studios-docker-compose-configuration). This official article just support Visual Studio in Windows.
[image]

**Sample:** *docker-compose.override.yml*

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  your-service-name:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - MYSECRETS__MYDBPASSWORD=MyPassValue
```

And if you deploy it to docker, you could use below command.

```
docker run -e ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+:443;http://+:80" -e MYSECRETS__MYDBPASSWORD=MyPassValue your-image-name
```

Comment: Thanks @jason-pan for your answer. Actually, the question wasn't about `How to make it work?` but `Why it works but I can't see env vars in my container?`